# Cart item is added with provider but removed during leaving product details screen (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, shopping-cart, flutter-provider

Cart item is added with the provider but removed during leaving product details screen. One question you may ask, How I know that product is added to the cart list? well, the answer is, I printed the length of the cart list after adding items with the provider.

Here is the cart class:

```
class Cart extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<CartProduct> _products = List<CartProduct>();

  String add(CartProduct product) {
  String message;

  if (_products.isEmpty) {
    _products.add(product);
    message = 'Successfuly added to Cart.';
  }

  notifyListeners();

  return message;
  }
}
```

And here is the add to cart onPressed method of Product details screen:

```
                  press: () {
                    String message = cart.add(CartProduct(
                      formName: formName,
                      id: productDetails.products.id,
                      name: productDetails.products.socialName,
                      price: productDetails.products.price.toDouble(),
                      quantity: 1,
                    ));
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: message);
                  },
```

This is the root widget where is put ChangeNotifierProvider:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Cart>(
      create: (context) => Cart(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Title',
        initialRoute: HomeScreen.routeName,
        routes: routes,
      ),
    );
  }
```

And this is the cart page:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context);

    return Padding(
      padding:
          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
      child: cart.products.length > 0
          ? ListView.builder(
              itemCount: cart.products.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
           ...................................
           ...................................
```

Comment: How do you leave the product details screen? Is it through the back button or you actually navigate to the next screen? Also, you said it does not show when you leave the product details screen. to where do you go after leaving the product details screen?

Comment: I leave the product details screen with a back button and go back to the home screen. And then, from the home screen, I go to the cart screen to see the cart but nothing is here.